# How to add image to image button within user controller for asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls, aspx-user-control

I have 2 projects. One is the main webform project and the second is a library project for my user controls. This library doesn't use file extension ascx. I have to be clear on this. My objective is to create an user controller that contains 1 textbox, 1 image button, 2 dropdown, 1 button and 1 calendar. Basically is a date picker controller. So far, everything is working. I can modify the calendar, populate month(dropdown) and year (dropdown). All buttons and actions behave correctly how I expect to behave. Even the image button when I click it; it display the calendar fine. I am having problem assigning the imageurl properties. I have copy the image to the library project, main project and nothing works. When running the main project is just shows a broken image. both project have the same name for the folder and file (~/Images/calendar4.png";). I have added this url in the usercontroller and in the main project and none works.

I have tried the following syntax on both project (one at a time):
(On Main Project)

```
string imgsource = "~/Images/calendar4.png";
ucpCalendar.ImageUrl = imgsource;
```

The I tried the following syntax:

```
string FullPathVirtual = Server.MapPath("~/Images/calendar4.png");
ucpCalendar.ImageUrl = FullPathVirtual;
```

The I tried this one:

```
string path = (Server.MapPath(".") + "//Images//" + "calendar4.png");
string imgPath = path.Replace("\\", "/").Replace("//", "/");
ucpCalendar.ImageUrl = imgPath ;
```

Here is my usercontroller code (I was trying to do a random image search to see if it finds a picture. Still didn't work):

```
public class pCalendar : UserControl
    {
        protected Calendar  cdatepicker;
        protected DropDownList ddrYear;
        protected DropDownList ddrMonth;
        protected ImageButton imbcalendar;
        protected TextBox txtbdatedisplay;
        protected Button btntoday;
        public pCalendar()
        {
            txtbdatedisplay = new TextBox();
            imbcalendar = new ImageButton();
            ddrMonth = new DropDownList();
            ddrYear = new DropDownList();
            btntoday = new Button();
            cdatepicker = new Calendar();
          
           
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\">"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("   <tr>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("       <td>"));
            Controls.Add(txtbdatedisplay);
            Controls.Add(imbcalendar);
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("       </td>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("   </tr>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("   <tr>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("       <td>"));
            Controls.Add(ddrMonth);
            Controls.Add(ddrYear);
            Controls.Add(btntoday);
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("       </td>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("   </tr>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("   <tr>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("       <td>"));
            Controls.Add(cdatepicker);
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("       </td>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("   </tr>"));
            Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</table>"));

        }
        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
           
            cdatepicker.VisibleDate = cdatepicker.TodaysDate;
            Hide();

            ControllersBasicInfo();
            
            int myYear = System.DateTime.Now.Year;
            int myMonth = System.DateTime.Now.Month;

            for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
            {
                ddrYear.Items.Add((myYear - i).ToString());
            }
            ddrYear.SelectedValue = myYear.ToString();
            ddrMonth.SelectedValue = myMonth.ToString();

            ddrMonth.AutoPostBack = true;
            ddrYear.AutoPostBack = true;

            ddrMonth.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(SetCalendarVisibleDate_SelectedIndexChanged);
            ddrYear.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(SetCalendarVisibleDate_SelectedIndexChanged);

            if (AutoPostBack)
            {
                ddrMonth.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
                ddrYear.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(ddl_SelectedIndexChanged);
              
            }
            imbcalendar.Click+=imbcalendar_Click;
            btntoday.Click += btntoday_Click;
            cdatepicker.SelectionChanged += cdatepicker_SelectionChanged;

            cdatepicker.DayRender += cdatepicker_DayRender;

            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        private void ControllersBasicInfo()
        {
            string FullPathVirtual = PickRandomImage2();
            //imbcalendar.ImageUrl = "~/Images/calendar4.png";
            imbcalendar.ImageUrl = FullPathVirtual;
        }
        private string PickRandomImage2()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string[] image = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath("~/image"), "*.jpg");
            string imageDisplay = image[rnd.Next(image.Length)];
            return imageDisplay;
        }
        public void BindData()
        {
            BindDataMonth();
        }
  
        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return this.imbcalendar.ImageUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                this.imbcalendar.ImageUrl = value;
            }
        }
}
```

the webform code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Calendar.aspx.cs" Inherits="IAS.Calendar" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="IAS.Controls" Namespace="IAS.Controls" TagPrefix="uc" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="/scripts/common.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="/scripts/jquery.extend-1.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Calendar/jscal2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Calendar/CSS/jscal2.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/Common.css" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <uc:pCalendar ID="ucpCalendar" runat="server"></uc:pCalendar>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
</form>
```

Code behind C#.net :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using lktec.Utils;

namespace TestCalendar
{
  public partial class Calendar : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ucpCalendar.BindData();
                //ucpCalendar.ImageUrl = "~/Images/calendar4.png";
             }
        }
   }
}
```

Here is an image of what is happening:
[Calendar display with other info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E87KX.png)

I have put only relevant code to my issue. If you need the full code please let me know. It is a lot of code. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Here is the suggested code to add:
using input tag:

```
string inputstring = @"<input type=""image""
                alt=""Clear button"" 
                src=""C:/Users/SANOZUKE/Documents/Visual Studio 2013/Projects/MHPPROJECT-English/IAS.root/IAS/IAS/Images/calendar4.png"" 
                onserverclick=""imbcalendar_Click"" 
                runat=""server""
                id=""imbcalendar"" />";
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work. Still shows no image on the controller.

Here is the picture:
[image: Adding Input Tag]

Comment: If you inspect the image in the developer tools, what is the value of `src`?

Comment: hi, is src not equal to imageurl of the imagebutton property?

Comment: Src is set based on ImageUrl and is what the browser requests, so no ~/ at the beginning, for instance. This must point to a file on the server, otherwise it results in a 404.

Comment: Hi, How can I add src to imagebutton? I double check the imagebutton properties and there is no scr or source in the list. I am using framework 2.0 if this helps.  Where do you recommend I add this src in the usercontrol? I even used a physical path.  (string FullPathVirtual = Server.MapPath("~/Images/calendar4.png");
ucpCalendar.ImageUrl = FullPathVirtual;).. This gives the following result: "C:\\Users\\SANOZUKE\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2013\\Projects\\MHPPROJECT-English\\IAS.root\I\AS\I\AS\\Images\\calendar4.png". This doesn't work either.

Comment: Your ImageButton is rendered as HTML when it is sent to the client. This results in HTML similar to the following: `<input type="image" name="ctl00$MainContent$imgBtn" id="MainContent_imgBtn" src="Content/logo.jpg">`. Notice the `src`. The browser uses this `src` to load the image. The "no image"-picture means that the browser cannot find the image at the specified URL. It might be helpful to know where the browser is looking for the image.

Comment: Hi Markus, I added the input tag in the usercontroller but didn't work. I have uploaded a picture in this question to show case what I did.

Comment: You do not need to add the `<input ...` manually. Your ImageButton is converted to it automatically when it is sent to the browser. Please use the Developer Tools in the browser to inspect the input (right click on the input, click "Inspect") to analyze the HTML that is generated and especially the value of the `src` attribute.

Comment: Hi Markus, Thank you for your help. I check the browser and in the usercontroller it shows the SRC as unknown. I check a normal a normal imagebutton in the webform directly and I saw how the path needs to be.  I change it from ~/Images/calendar4.png  to Images/calendar4.png.  Now, it displays the image.  Thank you so much.